# Wordpress custom loop pagination - always same content

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have one custom loop in a custom homepage in WordPress that is pulling 4 posts with some banners in middle. All is working fine, however pagination always shows same posts. Is there a way for me to add pagination to this custom loop?

My index.php code:

```
<?php
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'showposts' => 4,
) );
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 3) : ?>

<!-- banners -->

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h1> <?php the_title(); ?>  </h1>  </a>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h1> <?php the_title(); ?>  </h1>  </a>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<!-- banners -->

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>
```

Comment: you need to modify your Query to work with pagination, visit [documentations here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query)

Comment: That was my first try before opening post, sadly didn't make it to work.

Comment: Is that all code you have in index.php?

Comment: @beluoso Joint's answer is exactly from [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query) which I referred you to, are you sure you tried it before?

Comment: Sure did, I can see it it somewhat similar in there, couple minor differences that make it work: now with 'paged' => and in docs $paged =. Sorry but my skills are limited and I haven't tried that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your query_post array add this line:

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
```

and in settings -> reading set 4 posts per blog page.

Comment: Thanks J, edited everything but still got a blank page.

Comment: I updated my answer, I pasted your code in index.php and made a changes I wrote in answer and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks so much J, thats exactly it. Obrigado!